# HTTP POST and RESPONSE Action from Admin Dashboard

Tags: module, magento-1.9, dashboard

I am looking to build a module that needs to do POST actions then handle the response details.

I understand how to do this from the frontend but am unsure how to fully implement this within the dashboard. Are there any simple examples of this you could provide or recommend an extension that performs similar actions I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using CURL:

```
$url = 'https://example.org/connector.php';
$postData = array();
$postData['var2'] = join(',', $emails);
$postData['var3'] = 'amasty';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (strlen($result) > 2){
   //do something 
}
```

**edit**

You can use this code in admin controller created by this tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I know how to do this part, the problem is i am unsure how to properly implement it into the magento dashboard. I am familiar with doing it on the frontend but found few examples of creating a dashboard module with external functions only internal settings/actions.

Comment: Do you already have an admin controller that handles the get request? May be you can describe the task in more details?

Comment: Hello, at the moment I just have a blank admin page following Alan Storms tutorial "Magento Admin Hello World Revisited" That is all I have built thus far. I have not created any controllers yet, i figured I would have to do so but don't fully understand the magento file structure. I am familiar with creating forms that submit post data but I am not sure how to implement this int he magento file structure if that makes sense?

Comment: Anyways, I have a blank admin page I am a little unsure of how to properly build the look and fields of it and unsure how to properly build an http post form that will call to an external database.

Comment: Have updated the answer.